# Bash while loop + cut slow

Tags: bash, cut

I am trying to process a file (1.5GB) with a bash loop to iterate each line. I used `cut` for its simplicity (relative) and ended up with:

```
while read line
do
    echo "$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f 2-3)" "$(echo $line | cut -d'"' -f 20)"
done < TEST.log > IDS.log
```

This is very slow and only does about 2KB/sec. I need something to run a lot faster.

Also, what is the bottleneck here?

Comment: the bottleneck is forking, try a single awk or sed

Comment: It's hard to test an answer here without seeing a sample of your actual data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bottleneck is likely that you spawn several processes for every line of data. As for a replacement, this awk should be equivalent:

```
awk '{ split($0, a, "\""); print $2, $3, a[20] }' TEST.log > IDS.log
```

Comment: Mmmm why saying `print $2 " " $3`? Way cleaner to say `print $2, $3`, since the arguments will be separated by the default FS, that is, a space (which you are also setting).

Comment: I like that, so I put it in (even though it doesn't make a difference in this particular case).

Comment: Yep, note also that `-F ' '` is superfluous, since `FS=" "` is the default.

Comment: Hmm...I just looked that up because I thought the default separator was whitespaces in general -- which is the case, but a space as a field separator is [treated as this special case](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Default-Field-Splitting.html). It seems to work for OP as is, so I'll just remove the superfluous bit, but how would I tell awk to split at only spaces?

Comment: For posterity: `-F '[ ]'`

Comment: @Wintermute: To faithfully mimic the behavior of the `cut` command, you actually _have_ to use `-F '[ ]'` - `cut` always treats consecutive instances of the delimiter as separating an empty field.

Answer (score 4):

Perl is usually very fast:

```
perl -nE 'say join " ", (split " ")[1,2], (split /"/)[19]' TEST.log > IDS.log
```

Perl arrays are indexed starting with 0.

Comment: Nice, but Perl's `split " "` treats consecutive spaces as a _single_ separator, unlike the corresponding `cut` command in the OP, so your answer may behave differently - better to use `split / /`.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest bottleneck here is spinning off the subprocesses for your pipelines. You can get a substantial (read: orders-of-magnitude) performance improvement just by getting rid of the command substitutions and pipelines.

```
while IFS=$'\x01' read -r ss1 ss2 ss3 _ <&3 && \
      IFS='"' read -r -a quote_separated_fields; do
    printf '%s\n' "${ss2} ${ss3} ${quote_separated_fields[20]}"
done < TEST.log 3< <(tr ' ' $'\x01' <TEST.log) > IDS.log
```

How does this work?

- `tr ' ' $'\x01'` changes spaces in the input to a low-ASCII character to avoid special-case handling (where `read` will coalesce runs of whitespace into a single character). Putting this after `3< <(...)` puts the output of this operation on file descriptor #3.
- `IFS=$'\x01' read -r ss1 ss2 ss3 _ <&3` splits a line on those characters, putting the first field into `ss1` (which we don't care about), the second into `ss2`, the third into `ss3`, and the remainder of the line into `_`. The `<&3` causes this line to read from file descriptor 3.
- `IFS='"' read -r -a quote_separated_fields` splits input on stdin (FD 0) on `"` characters into an array called `quote_separated_fields`.